# How do you unblock or access Plugins, Tools and Settings in the WordPress WP-Admin when they are not available?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have paid someone to create a dynamic classified website for me. The website was created in WordPress. I was given administrator access to the website, however I am not able to access the Plugins, Tools and Settings on the WP-Admin Dashboard. I will be needing those to be available for functionality of the website.
[What I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJXdl.jpg)

I expected to see to see the following:
[What I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgJMo.jpg)

I have administrator access to the site as well as access to the web hosting. I am unable to contact the web developer that developed the site.

Please tell me how I would be able to unblock or access Plugins, Tools and Settings in the WP-Admin Dashboard based on what I have available.

Comment: One option is the developer use a plugin called "User Role Editor" to manage roles and capabilities (Check this post: https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/hide-admin-menu-items-for-specific-users-in-wordpress/). Another option is removing them programaticaly (see here how: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134455/69644).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of having an admin role? You can check this by creating an admin user from the code. If you have access to your Hosting, then this article can help https://wphub.me/create-new-wordpress-admin-user-programmatically/.